# How to export an Excel from dataset and save it into a specific path without showing the save as box

Tags: c#, excel, path, export

I have a code to exporting dataset to excel working fine, I want to exporting the excel into a specific location on the server, my code is down here and what changes should I do: Any ideas?

```
public static void ExportDataSetToExcel(DataSet ds, string filename, string path)
{
   HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.Clear();
    response.Charset = "";
    response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\""+filename+"\"");
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            // instantiate a datagrid
            DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
            dg.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            dg.DataBind();
            dg.RenderControl(htw);
            response.Write(sw.ToString());
            response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to save the Excel file from a website to a local file? Or are you trying to send the Excel file somewhere? Your code seems to conflict with your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible to download the way you are describing.  That would be a large security risk if browsers allowed this.

Comment: To MattB:
How about put it into the server

Comment: If you are wanting to put it onto the server, you'll want to actually write it to a file (FileWriter) not use the HttpResponse.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible.  The browser can't directly access the user's file system because of the obvious security risks that would entail.  If you are providing a file download service from your website, you have to accept that the user will be prompted with the 'Save File' dialog by the browser.

Comment: to pnarflee:
How about put the excel file into location which is in the server

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to save to a file, you only need to use the StringWriter class. You need to add the path for the file to be saved into the constructor for the StringWriter, as so (assuming the path does not include the filename. And you need to close the StringWriter:

```
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(path + filename))
{
    // use 'sw.Write(text)' to write to the file
    sw.Close();
}
```

EDIT: If you want to push the Excel file to a server, you need to use some other method. You can't push HTTP requests like that.

Comment: thanks, what method can I use, kind of System.IO.WriteAllBytes? Do u know which method can I use? Please give me a hint.

Comment: I can not using "using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(path + filename))" give me an error, I am thinking if I can save it in the specific local directory, then I can use this directory to upload the file.

Answer (score 0):

I made it working, by using  FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("ExcelFile\File1.xls"), FileMode.Create);
        try
        {
            Byte[] bContent = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8").GetBytes(htmlmarkup);
            fs.Write(bContent, 0, bContent.Length);
        }
it can create the file into server and use the code on my post can use the xls on your local disk. I conbined the two method it works fine for me